# Change search form placeholder text

Tags: javascript, placeholder

I need to change search form placeholder text with JavaScript.

I have a mega menu search item with id `#mega-menu-item-search-6`.
Inside of it I have a search form with class `.mk-searchform` and id `#searchform`.

I wrote this but it doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById("mega-menu-item-search-6").attr("placeholder", "Search product");
```

Comment: You are mixing plain JS and jQuery syntax - setAttribute is JS

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.setAttribute()`

```js
document.getElementById("mega-menu-item-search-6").setAttribute("placeholder", "Search product");
```

```html
<form class="mk-searchform" id="searchform">
  <input type="text" id="mega-menu-item-search-6">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Javascript and jQuery. `.attr()` is jQuery method. And you are selecting DOM element with JS.

So, you can either use jQuery:

```
$("#mega-menu-item-search-6").attr("placeholder", "Search product");
```

Or Javascript;

```
document.getElementById("mega-menu-item-search-6").placeholder = "Search product";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try like in javascript

```
document.getElementById('mega-menu-item-search-6').placeholder='Search product';
```

OR in JQuery

```
$('#mega-menu-item-search-6').attr('placeholder','Search product');
```

i hope it will help you.